# asp.net DetailsView programmatic data access

Tags: c#, detailsview

How to programmatically browse through the pages of a data-bound DetailsView?

I am using this code:

```
protected void DetailsView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, DetailsViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            DetailsView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        }
```

The page is changing. But the problem is, the next record item is not showing up. The old item is still visible on the new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-bind your details view.